# Does fetching a mysql array with MYSQL_ASSOC rather than MYSQL_BOTH affect performance

Tags: mysql, arrays, performance

Simple question I can't seem to find the answer to.

I'm trying to squeeze some more performance out of this large app and I'm wondering if switching all of the mysql_fetch_array() function calls to only use MYSQL_ASSOC will make any difference.
It seems like it would since it's creating an array with just:

```
$row['field1'] = 'field1-value';
```

instead of both numeric and associative keys for the same field:

```
$row[0] = 'field1-value';
$row['field1'] = 'field1-value';
```

Comment: When you mysql both and when you loop through the array each row is repeated again and i think in almost all cases we need either a numeric or associative array only.. SO its always better to retrieve what we need .. MYSQL_BOTH means unnecessary storage in arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two concepts prevalent in this scenario, which you must consider:-

1. It is always helpful to use the associative indices of "`MYSQL_ASSOC`" / "`MYSQL_BOTH`", instead of just using the numerical indices, because the order of the fields may change in the lifetime of the website. If you understand & agree with this point, then you can use the "`MYSQL_ASSOC`" result type, instead of the "`MYSQL_BOTH`" result type.
2. If you are concerned about how much memory is being used for queries that return large result sets, then you can use "[`mysql_free_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-free-result.html)" function. More details of this function can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-free-result.html). However, all the associated result memory is automatically freed at the end of the script's execution.

Now, coming back to your question, I think that from a performance point of view, using "`MYSQL_ASSOC`" result type may result in saving a little bit of memory of the server (where the website has been hosted, when the relevant web page is being executed by the PHP Parser), but you must also ensure & understand the above points as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains it well.  The situation is that the mysql_fetch_array() function defaults to MYSQL_BOTH, so since when we started building this app it has been using that default.  Some parts of the app might take advantage of the numerical indices rather than associative, so I was just looking to see if it's worth it to make the switch to only MYSQL_ASSOC and then go through to pick out potential bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same question. To get a better idea, I ran a little experiment:

I ran the same query three times (with MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_BOTH and MYSQL_NUM respectively) for several times to get three average timings. Turned out that in my experiment MYSQL_NUM was about 17% faster than MYSQL_ASSOC, and MYSQL_ASSOC was about 16% faster than MYSQL_BOTH.

I'm sure my little experiment has its flaws, but I'm confident it goes into the right direction.

So I'd say MYSQL_ASSOC gives you a good compromise because you can still switch columns in your table...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT candidate.cand_number, candidate.cand_fname, candidate.cand_desc 
        FROM candidate ".$join.' 
        WHERE '.$condition;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide some explanation to your answer as well.